# Java backtracking in a maze

Tags: java, backtracking, maze

I'm writing a program that will essentially have an object searching for a "pig" by using java backtracking. As of now, I have the pig moving and searching but it's unable to actually "backtrack".  I'm just completely lost on how to actually go about implementing the code for that segment, but I do know that you would use pathIndex-- to decrease the path length. Any help on how to go about doing this would be extremely helpful.

```
public class MazeWalker {
    /**
     * The possible states of the current "walk" through a maze.
     */
    public enum WalkerState {
        /**
         * Indicates that the maze walker has reached its assigned destination.
         */
        THERE_ALREADY,

        /**
         * Indicates that the maze walker has concluded that it is impossible to
         * reach its destination.
         */
        IMPOSSIBLE_TO_GET_THERE,

        /**
         * Indicates that the maze walker would like to move left.
         */
        MOVE_LEFT,

        /**
         * Indicates that the maze walker would like to move up.
         */
        MOVE_UP,

        /**
         * Indicates that the maze walker would like to move right.
         */
        MOVE_RIGHT,

        /**
         * Indicates that the maze walker would like to move down.
         */
        MOVE_DOWN
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the MazeWalker, providing it with the maze to use and the
     * walker's destination.
     */
    public MazeWalker(Maze maze, int destinationX, int destinationY) {
        this.maze = maze;
        this.destinationX = destinationX;
        this.destinationY = destinationY;

        // The path stack starts out empty.
        path = new WalkerState[this.maze.getMazeWidth() * this.maze.getMazeHeight()];
        pathIndex = -1;

        // The "been-there" array starts off completely clear.
        beenThere = new boolean[this.maze.getMazeHeight()][this.maze.getMazeWidth()];
        for (int row = 0; row < beenThere.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < beenThere[row].length; column++) {
                beenThere[row][column] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Takes a step toward reaching the given destination from the given current
     * location, and returns either the direction of the next step, whether or
     * not that destination has been reached, or whether that destination is
     * impossible to reach.
     */
    public WalkerState areWeThereYet(int currentX, int currentY) {
      ///currentWalkerState =

      if ((currentX == destinationX) && (currentY == destinationY)) {
        return WalkerState.THERE_ALREADY;

      } else if (maze.getLocation(currentX, currentY).getRight().isOpen() && !beenThere[currentY][currentX + 1]) {

      ///  currentWalkerState = WalkerState.MOVE_RIGHT;
        pathIndex++;
        path[pathIndex] = WalkerState.MOVE_RIGHT;
        return WalkerState.MOVE_RIGHT;

      } else if (maze.getLocation(currentX, currentY).getLeft().isOpen() && !beenThere[currentY][currentX - 1]) {

      ///  currentWalkerState = WalkerState.MOVE_LEFT;
        pathIndex++;
        path[pathIndex] = WalkerState.MOVE_LEFT;
        return WalkerState.MOVE_LEFT;

      } else if (maze.getLocation(currentX, currentY).getAbove().isOpen() && !beenThere[currentY + 1][currentX]) {

      ///  currentWalkerState = WalkerState.MOVE_UP;
        pathIndex++;
        path[pathIndex] = WalkerState.MOVE_UP;
        return WalkerState.MOVE_UP;

      } else if (maze.getLocation(currentX, currentY).getBelow().isOpen() && !beenThere[currentY - 1][currentX]) {

      ///  currentWalkerState = WalkerState.MOVE_DOWN;
        pathIndex++;
        path[pathIndex] = WalkerState.MOVE_DOWN;
        return WalkerState.MOVE_DOWN;
      }
        ///Returning 6 different values///
        ///MazeWalker is the thing thats moving///
        ///MazeWalker is initialized with a Maze Object with the desired destination coordinates///
        ///Steve's initial location is sx, sy///
        ///Pig's location is px, py///

      return WalkerState.IMPOSSIBLE_TO_GET_THERE;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a representation of the locations which the walker has visited.
     * The 2D array's dimensions should correspond to those of the walker's
     * assigned maze.
     */
    public boolean[][] getBeenThere() {
        return beenThere;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the current path taken by the walker.
     */
    public WalkerState[] getCurrentPath() {
        WalkerState[] currentPath = new WalkerState[pathIndex + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < pathIndex + 1; i++) {
            currentPath[i] = path[i];
        }
        return currentPath;
    }

    /**
     * The data structure for maintaining the current path.
     */
    private WalkerState[] path;

    /**
     * The index for the current node in the path.
     */
    private int pathIndex;

    /**
     * The data structure for keeping track of "passed" squares.
     */
    private boolean[][] beenThere;

    /**
     * The maze that is being walked.
     */
    private Maze maze;

    /**
     * The x-coordinate of the walker's destination.
     */
    private int destinationX;

    /**
     * The y-coordinate of the walker's destination.
     */
    private int destinationY;
}
```

Comment: Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote this in *C++* but the ideas can easily be transferred to Java. Note that it is typical to use **recursion** when implementing a backtracking algorithmic approach.

#### Author's Notes

Note that I use a Cell class and a Maze class. The variable "matrix" is a two-dimensional array in the Maze class and each [row][column] location in the matrix holds a Cell object. Each Cell holds boolean variables that determine its attributes (is it a wall?, has it been visited?, is it the start?, or the finish?, etc.).

### Backtracking Maze Solver

```
/**
 * determines whether path to maze can be found using backtracking 
 * algorithm
 */

 bool MazeSolver::backtrackingFindPath(Cell toCell) {

    // if cell moving to is not valid, return false
    if (!maze.isValidMove(toCell)) {
        return false;
    }

    // (base case) if cell moving to is finish, return true
    if (maze.matrix[toCell.getRow()][toCell.getCol()].getIsFinish()) {
        return true;
    }

    // if cell moving to is already visited, return false
    if (maze.matrix[toCell.getRow()][toCell.getCol()].getIsVisited()) {
        return false;
    }

    else {

        // get row and column of cell moving to
        int row = toCell.getRow();
        int col = toCell.getCol();

        // move to this cell in maze and set as visited
        // store cell moved to in solution path
        maze.move(maze.matrix[row][col]);

        // if simply returned function call, first invalid cell would
        // return a false value and exit function
        // by wrapping in if statement, still calls function recursively
        // but only returns value if moves to maze to stop recursion

        // recurse north / up, if moves to finish, return true
        if (backtrackingFindPath(maze.matrix[row - 1][col]) == true)
            return true;
        // recurse east / right
        if (backtrackingFindPath(maze.matrix[row][col + 1]) == true)
            return true;
        // recurse south / down
        if (backtrackingFindPath(maze.matrix[row + 1][col]) == true)
            return true;
        // recurse west / left
        if (backtrackingFindPath(maze.matrix[row][col - 1]) == true)
            return true;

        // no valid or unvisited cells were available from this cell
        // set as bad path and remove from solution path
        maze.unmove(maze.matrix[toCell.getRow()][toCell.getCol()]);

        // return false and go back to previous function call
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

### Helper Methods

Determines whether a move can really be made in the maze.

```
/**
 * is valid move
 */
bool isValidMove(Cell toCell) {

    int row = toCell.getRow();
    int col = toCell.getCol();

    // check if within bounds of maze
    if ((row >= 0 && row < rows) && (col >= 0 && col < cols)) {

        // if not a wall
        if (!matrix[row][col].getIsWall()) {

            // if not a bad path
            if (!matrix[row][col].getIsBadPath()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Actually makes the move, pushes the Cell onto a stack which represents the solution path.

```
/**
 * move (forward) in maze
 */
void move(Cell goodCell) {

    // set cell moving to as visited
    matrix[goodCell.getRow()][goodCell.getCol()].setIsVisited(true);

    // update current location in maze to cell moving
    setCurrent(goodCell);

    // store cell moved to in stack (solution path)
    path.push(goodCell);
}
```

Goes backward, pops the most recently saved Cell from the stack representing the solution path.

```
/**
 * unmove (move back) in maze
 */
void unmove(Cell badCell) {

    // set cell leaving as bad path
    matrix[badCell.getRow()][badCell.getCol()].setIsBadPath(true);
    matrix[badCell.getRow()][badCell.getCol()].setIsVisited(false);

    // remove cell leaving from stack (solution path)
    path.pop();
}
```

Here's a [**good reference**](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/alg/maze/) for understanding why this is backtracking and why it works.